# React Native Android: Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: android, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I've added `react-native-fbsdk` to my react native project and have it building fine on iOS. But on the android side, I can't get gradle to build the project. When trying to compile react-native-fbsdk, I'm hitting: "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

```
21:41:11.863 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler] Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
21:41:12.100 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/joncursi/Sites/joncursi/redbirdNative/node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBSDKPackage.java:61: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Which points to the following code snippet within react-native-fbsdk:

```
@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

When I delete `@Override`, this particular instance of the error goes away, but I hit the same error in another module such as `react-native-image-picker`:

```
:react-native-image-picker:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
/Users/joncursi/Sites/joncursi/redbirdNative/node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android/src/main/java/com/imagepicker/ImagePickerPackage.java:34: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
1 error
```

I suspect this to be an issue with my local setup. Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Comment: How did you solve this issue? Was there an easy fix?

Comment: Upgraded react native fbsdk

Comment: Yea I manually edited the packages throwing errors....

Answer (score 14):

The error is very vague (and imo a bit of a mess up in the react native release flow).

React-native 0.47.0 had a breaking change that meant libs had to patch their code.

> Remove unused createJSModules calls (ce6fb33, 53d5504) - [source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.47.0)

My guess is that you just have to update the libraries for which this error shows up, and otherwise submit a PR.

Here's an example of a lib fixing it: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/pull/191/files

**Update:**

The PR you're waiting for is here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/354